# how to clear div contents in Angular ? (angular 7)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tried

```
    let graphDiv = document.querySelector('div#graphDiv').innerHTML;
    graphDiv.clear();

or

   graphDiv.destroy();
```

didn't find answer in google search.
my div content is randomly generated (hence I was using Math.random() to pre-fill a graph ). I want to clear the div content itself via the component and not through the html template.

Comment: `<div *ngIf="condition"></div>` empty div

Comment: my div content is randomly generated. I want to clear the div content itself via the component and not through the html template

Comment: In angular it's usually easiest to update some variable and have the template respond. In niche situations it's possible to pull of what you are trying to do (i.e., programmatically changing the contents of a component) but it's rarely useful or worth the effort. I would take @Train's advice if I were you. There's probably a way to do it.

Comment: Also Angular uses a virtual DOM and besides innerHTML returns a string, so what you are doing here would never work anyway.

Answer (score 3):

In Angular, JavaScript own techniques is not recommended. Using Angular feature is recommended for DOM manipulation.

Below is my approach for DOM manipulation.

(I use @Component in below code but @Directive is recommended for rendering job)

(I'm also learning Anguler as beginner. If any error or better solution, please share)

A. File structure as Component

- graph.component.html
- graph.component.ts

B. Angular Code

B-1. in **graph.component.html**

```
<div #graphDiv></div>
```

B-2. in **graph.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Renderer2, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './graph.component.html'
})

export class GraphComponent {
    @ViewChild("graphDiv") graphDiv: ElementRef;

    constructor(private renderer:Renderer2) {
    }

    clearDiv() {
        let valueYouWantToPut = "cleared";
        this.renderer.setProperty(this.graphDiv.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', valueYouWantToPut)
    }
}
```

for further study, please refer to below site as I did:
https://indepth.dev/posts/1336/how-to-do-dom-manipulation-properly-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
 document.querySelector('div#graphDiv').innerHTML = "";
```

(though approaches pointed out in comments would be better)

Comment: core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: It seems it could not find your element. Console log out what document.querySelector('div#graphDiv') returns and try to fix the query to find the element

Answer (score 0):

## Old question but I feel it is necessary

## A brief intro

- I do like [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68591859/8784518). But TBH I love separating things into their own section. So I like to give you a sales pitch about using custom directives.
- **I test it in Angular 14**
- **Using `Renderer2` has a good reason, We could do the same task with `ElementRef` but we do not. Why? because Angular can render your template without a DOM. So if that was the case we won't have access to DOM attributes, right? Not convinced? So for example when we use [service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro). Though I confess that it is an advance topic, but nonetheless accessing DOM directly is not a good practice.**
- Use `@Input` decorator to pass value to the directive

## My Solution

1. `ng g d shared/directives/clear-div`

   - Or do this if it is restricted to a specific component/module `ng g d [component name/module name]/directives/clear-div`
2. Copy and paste this code in it:

```
import {
    Directive,
    ElementRef,
    Renderer2,
    OnInit,
    HostListener,
    // Input,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appClearDiv]',
})
export class ClearDivDirective implements OnInit {
    // @Input() newContent: string;
    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer2,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // If you need to do anything on init
    }

    // Obviously you have to select your desired event.
    @HostListener('mouseenter')
    mouseEnter(eventData: Event) {
        this.renderer.setProperty(
            this.elementRef.nativeElement,
            'innerHTML',
            // this.newContent,
            'Hello from Kasir Barati', // Put anything you like
        );
    }
}
```

3. Now let's use it in our template

```html
<!-- <div appClearDiv [newContent]="'Hello from Kasir'"> -->
<div appClearDiv class="row">
    <div class="col-12">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

## Disclaimer

Obviously there is not perfect solution but as far as I am concerned this is a better solution.